# Get HMR working with webpack/react in chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, webpack-hmr

I am currently developing a browser extension (both on Chrome and Firefox but let's take the usual case: Chrome) and I am using webpack with react for developing the popup.

My question is: is it possible to have Hot Module Reloading (HMR) working in this popup/tab (you can get the html file with react working in a tab) ?

I tried to use react-hot-loader but I can't figure out how to make it work in an extension.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.